# Why is website using a different version of PHP to localhost?

Tags: php, visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I am using Windows 10 and IIS 10 with Visual Studio Community 2017.

When I check the version of PHP running on localhost using http://localhost/phpinfo.php, PHP Version 7.2.7 is displayed.

However, when I use Visual Studio to run phpinfo.php from the root of a site in C:\Users\username\My Documents\My Web Sites\Website1, i.e. http://localhost:4782/phpinfo.php, PHP Version 5.3.28 is displayed.

Can anyone please tell me why Visual Studio is not using PHP version 7.2.7 like the root of localhost is and what I need to do for the website to run on PHP version 7.2.7?

I prefer IIS Manager, to cmd prompt.

Comment: IIS allows multiple PHP versions for different sites, so you need a tool like PHP Manager to select what version you want, https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases

Comment: Thanks for you replies.  I’m using Windows 10 and IIS.  Not Ubuntu or Apache.  I’m aware I’m running multiple versions of PHP. I’ve been looking into this on and off for 2 days now. I suppose I need to know why PHP version 5.3 is used when the site runs in Visual Studio Community 2017, but the root of localhost shows PHP v7.2. I need to update a Joomla site so it works on PHP v7.2 and I can’t do it until I get this resolved.

Comment: Thanks @Lex Li. But, won't PHP Manager just change the PHP version at localhost though? It doesn't answer the question of why different versions are being used.

Comment: @Stephen Kennedy, why have you removed the link to the answer by edit?

Comment: Dani, The questions box is for questions and not for answers. If you have an answer, you can answer the question yourself in the answer box or if it's just a link, leave a comment. If you've found a duplicate question on Stack Overflow which answers your question, you can flag your post as a duplicate, then refresh the page. There should be a visible yellow box that asks if it's a dupe; click "yes" to close their question. Hope that helps explain my edit and how you can proceed. Thanks.